# PHP 7.2 discontinued writing logs?

Tags: php

PHP-FPM not writing logs after upgrade from 7.1 to 7.2.

Below conf file. The environment is CentOS, Nginx.

```
;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M

; Set data paths to directories owned by process user
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/fpm/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/fpm/wsdlcache
;php_value[opcache.file_cache]  = /var/lib/php/fpm/opcache
```

Comment: Is this within a docker container?

Comment: This is from www.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Make these settings in `www.conf`

```
catch_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Also, don't forget to create a log file, so php-fpm can write on it:

```
touch /var/log/fpm-php.www.log && chmod 777 /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
```